# Django link does not display new template

Tags: python, html, django

I'm just starting with django/web development and I've run into a problem. In my templates folder I have base.html, home.html and licences.html templates. In the home.html I have a link `<li><a href="{% url 'licences' %}">Licences</a></li>` and in my views.py I have the method licences(request):

```
def licences(request):
    return render(request, "licences.html", {})
```

However if I then run the server and click the link, I get the a blank page with just the base.html elements being displayed.

How do I fix this to display the new page?

EDIT:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', 'searchFilm.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^results/$', 'searchFilm.views.results', name='results'),
    url(r'^licences/$', 'searchFilm.views.licences', name='licences')

]
```

licences.html

```
<html>

    <head>
        <!-- <title>{% block title %}HomePage{% endblock %}</title> -->
    </head>

    <body>

        <p>This page contians informations on the licences</p>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does your `urls.py` file look like?

Comment: Hi I've updated my question

Comment: What does the `licences.html` template look like?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question again

Comment: Please also include base.html

Comment: Hi, thanks this comment helped me work out the problem, I needed to put the  <p>This page contians informations on the licences</p> between {% block content %} and it worked, but I'm not sure why since licences.html doesnt extend base.html

Comment: This is what I don't understand it shouldn't be extending base.html since {% extends "base.html" %} isn't my licences.html, my home page does extend base.html however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out what the problem was, turns out you can't comment out Django tags using HTML comments, so even though {% extends "base.html" %} was inside a comment, the page was still extending base.html. If I completely removed the extends tag, or changed licences.html to comply with base.html it worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Have you populated your licenses table( do you have data in your licenses table)? The main reason you get a blank table is because you are missing one line of code between your **def** statement and **return** statement, you need a query statement like:

```
licences=nameOfYourLicencesTable.objects.get(pk=id)
```

Then you can use at your template:

```
<li><a href="{{ licenses.licensesColumnName}}">Licences</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to see the structure of base.html but i think u r not Including base.html